# How Can I Handle Alerts In Selenium's Javascript Web Driver?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

There are several other questions like this one (ie. questions about `alert` in Selenium) for non-Javascript versions of WebDriver.  In the answers for those questions, the general pattern recommended is:

```
try {
    doSomethingWhichCausesAnAlert();
} catch(UnexpectedAlertOpenError e) {
    doSomethingAboutException(e);
}
```

However, I can't copy that pattern in the Javascript version, because everything is asynchronous:

```
try {
    doSomethingWhichCausesAnAlert();
} catch(e) {
    // this will never get reached
}
// 1ms or more later the alert appears, causing an exception
```

I thought perhaps I could use a `.catch`:

```
el.sendKeys('invalid keystrokes that cause an alert')
  .catch((e) => doSomethingWithException(e))
```

but that doesn't work either; it seems like the `alert` exception happens after that `catch` has resolved.

**TLDR**

**How can I catch `alert` exceptions (and then do something about the alert) when they all seem to happen outside the context of my code?**

By the way, here's an example stack trace of an alert exception:

```
UnexpectedAlertOpenError: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : Please enter a valid number ("not a number" is not a number).}
   (Session info: chrome=53.0.2785.116)
   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.23.409687 (c46e862757edc04c06b1bd88724d15a5807b84d1),platform=Linux 4.4.0-21-generic x86_64)
     at WebDriverError (/home/me/project/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:27:5)
     at UnexpectedAlertOpenError (/home/me/project/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:274:5)
     at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/home/me/project/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:512:13)
     at parseHttpResponse (/home/me/project/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:396:13)
     at doSend.then.response (/home/me/project/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:328:11)
     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.manage().deleteAllCookies()
     at Driver.schedule (/home/me/project/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:414:17)
     at Options.deleteAllCookies (/home/me/project/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:1178:25)
     at World.<anonymous> (/home/me/project/test/cucumber/features/support/Hooks.js:23:37)
     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
```

As you can see, the only part of my code that's even involved is my `Hooks.js` file, which causes the error when it tries to call:

```
this.driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

to clean up the cookies in a `this.After` (obviously `After` the test completes it's too late for me to do anything about the `alert`).

P.S. I found a hacky way to at least confirm that an alert is present before `After` is triggered: if I call `this.driver.manage().deleteAllCookies()` in a step after the alert appears, it will cause the exception to occur.  However, A) I don't want to delete cookies just to detect an `alert`, and B) I still have no way of actually closing the `alert`.

Answer (score 2):

As the founders of Stack Overflow are fond of saying, I should have just "read the source Luke!"  When I did I was able to work backwards and eventually figure out the JS pattern, which is:

```
// in a step or logic that goes off after the alert appears

this.driver.switchTo().alert().then((alert) => alert.dismiss());
```

Hope this helps other JS/Selenium users.